# Issue with Woocommerce Checkout Processing

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

The issue is related to the checkout process in WooCommerce. Additionally, I would like to bring to your attention that the checkout request is not being processed when the product price is set to 0.

Upon testing the checkout https://margsatyajeevan.com/checkout/ process, I encountered an error message stating “Error processing checkout. Please try again.” This error occurs when a product with a price of 0 is in the cart. It seems that the checkout request is not being processed as expected in this scenario.

The request to https://margsatyajeevan.com/?wc-ajax=checkout is not processing and gives 500 error.

To troubleshoot the issue, I have followed the recommended steps, including, clearing caching plugins, and disabling conflicting plugins or customizations. Unfortunately, the issue persists, and I have been unable to identify the root cause.

I kindly request your assistance in resolving this matter. It would be greatly appreciated if you could investigate the issue and provide guidance or a potential solution to ensure the smooth processing of checkout requests when a virtual product with a price of 0 is involved.

Answer (score 1):

That was the server configuration issue, I asked my hosting provider to transfer the server to a different location. After the server transfer, the issue automatically got resolved.